# Zen coding in .php extension with Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, emmet, sublimetext2

I'm used to doing zen coding in `.html` file and it works! But I cant figure out how to do the same when im in `.php` file, tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> too but nothing happened. I'm working on a Joomla website so the theme file will be in `.php` and not in `.html` but there are so many HTML tags to type. I even tried adding this setting in `zen-coding.sublime.settings` and saved it in user folder but nothing happened. Why won't it work? This is where I got the reference from [link](http://andrewblogs.com/blog/zen-coding-php-zen-coding-custom-snippet-example/), however its used in Zen Coding.js but the syntax are the same even in ST2. The Snippets are just additional settings but the main things is HTML zen-coding abbreviations won't appear in `.php` file but its working in `.html`. Anybody can solve this?

```
"my_zen_settings" : {
    "html": {
        "filters": "php,html",
        "abbreviations": {
            "jq": "<script src='jquery.js' type='javascript'>",
            "demo": "<div id=\"demo\"></div>"
        }
    },
    "css": {
        "filters": "html,css,fc",
        "snippets": {
            "c": "color:#${1:000000};"
        }
    },
    "php": {
       "filters": "php,html",
       "snippets": {
            "php":          "<?php | ?>",
            "php:info":     "<?php\nphpinfo();\n?>",
            "php:echo":     "<?php echo | ?>",

            "php:Ns":       "<?php\nnamespace |;\n\t\n?>",
            "php:ns":       "namespace |;",

            "php:Class":    "<?php\nclass |\n{\n\t\n}\n?>",
            "php:class":    "class |\n{\n\t\n}",

            "php:Function": "<?php\nfunction |() {\n\t\n}\n?>",
            "php:function": "function |() {\n\t\n}",

            "php:Var":      "<?php $| = ; ?>",
            "php:var":      "$| = ;",

            "php:Object":   "<?php $| = (object) ; ?>",
            "php:object":   "$| = (object) ;",

            "php:New":      "<?php $| = new ; ?>",
            "php:new":      "$| = new ;",

            "php:Bool":     "<?php $| = FALSE; ?>",
            "php:bool":     "$| = FALSE;",

            "php:Array":    "<?php $| = array(); ?>",
            "php:array":    "$| = array();",


            "php:Array+":   "<?php |[] = ; ?>",
            "php:array+":   "|[] = ;",

            "php:Array-":   "<?php unset($|[]); ?>",
            "php:array-":   "unset($|[]);",

                        //hack $|, seems to replace $i with $1
            "php:For":      "<?php\nfor ($|i = 0; $|i < |; $|i++) {\n\t\n}\n?>",
            "php:for":      "for ($|i = 0; $|i < |; $|i++) {\n\t\n}",

            "php:Foreach":  "<?php\nforeach (| as ) {\n\t\n}\n?>",
            "php:foreach":  "foreach (| as ) {\n\t\n}",

            "php:While":    "<?php\nwhile(|) {\n\t\n}\n?>",
            "php:while":    "while(|) {\n\t\n}",

            "php:Dowhile":  "<?php\ndo {\n\t\n} while(|);\n?>",
            "php:dowhile":  "do {\n\t\n} while(|);",

            "php:If":       "<?php if( | ) { ?>\n\t\n<?php }?>",
            "php:if":       "if( | ) {\n\t\n}",

            "php:Ifelse":   "<?php if( | ) { ?>\n\t\n<?php } else { ?>\n\t\n<?php }?>",
            "php:ifelse":   "if( | ) {\n\t\n} else {\n\t\n}",

            "php:Switch":   "<?php switch( | ) { \n\tcase :\n\t\t\n\t\tbreak;\n\tdefault :\n\t\t\n\t\tbreak;\n}\n?>",
            "php:switch":   "switch( | ) { \n\tcase :\n\t\t\n\t\tbreak;\n\tdefault :\n\t\t\n\t\tbreak;\n}",

            "php:Include":  "<?php include \"|\"; ?>",
            "php:include":  "include \"|\";",

            "php:Include1": "<?php include_once \"|\"; ?>",
            "php:include1": "include_once \"|\";"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem. Tried the following :

1. preferences > browse package > Default (OSX).sublime-keymap
2. found the "operand" index where "keys" = ctrl + alt + enter
3. added "text.php" to that string. like this : ***"source.css - source.css.embedded, text.xml, text.html -source -meta.tag, meta.scope.between-tag-pair.html -source , text.php"***

That seemed to do the trick. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Emmet for Sublime Text 2:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

**Notice :** Emmet (ex-Zen Coding).

Answer (score 0):

adding text.php to Default (Windows).sublime-keymap worked for me.